# Get user access token on Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I try to get access token on Facebook API.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134217/2069858) I need first to build a link `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[Your API KEY]&redirect_url=[Service that will handle Authentication]&scope=[Permissions you Need]`. In my case it looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=559149457475028&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_stream
```

After this it should redirect to specified url with a query string containing code, which in turn can be used to get access token of a user. But in my case it redirects to the following page: `http://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_` without any queries.

Why is that? How I can get code of a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `redirect_uri` shouldn't be `http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` it should be a url from your application that would handle facebook authentication

**update**

if you are still developing your website and you want to test it on your local host you could use `localhost/mydevwebsite/login_success/` otherwise use the domain for the application you are working on `myappdomain.com/loginsuccess/`

Comment: It's not me. Where can I read about making this url? Can I find code or access token in a different way?

Comment: if you are still developing your website and you want to test it on your local host you could use `localhost/mydevwebsite/login_success/` other wise use the domain for the application you are working on

Comment: I've also edited the question to include this comment, as it might be helpful

Comment: Indeed, with site URL it redirects with query string.

Comment: Will it increase your reputation?

Comment: yes it will, you should read [this article] about how to earn reputation on stackoverflow(http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: you will also get [this badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/10/scholar) for it

Comment: =) Ok, just asked for fun.

Answer (score 0):

1. Access the `signed_request` parameter and prompt the user to authorize your app:

   ```
   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

   $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

   $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

   $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

   list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

   $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

   if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
       echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
   } else {
       echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
   }
   ```
2. This signed_request contains whole damn required information (including access token).

Comment: I have no experience working in PHP. Can you translate it to Python?

Comment: And I've no exp with python, but Ill explain you the concept. `$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];` step triies to fetch the variable singed_request from the url; if it is found, you can save the access token and perform functions, else it will redirect user to auth_url for the authorization step and the process is repeated.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python. But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[Your API KEY]&redirect_url=[Service that will handle Authentication]&scope=[Permissions you Need].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may help answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of an explanation.